# Does $ \int \exp(-ax^{3/2}+bx) dx $ have a solution?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Does following integral have a solution?
$$
\int \exp(-ax^{3/2}+bx) dx
$$

Where a and b are constants.

It seems to be straightforward problem but I couldn't find the solution using wolframalpha.

Comment: Well, for $a=b=0$ we have the integral equals $x+c$.

Comment: One parameter between $a$ and $b$ is completely useless. Anyway, you may just expand $e^{bx}$ as a Taylor series and perform a termwise integration against $e^{-a x^{3/2}}$. You will get a series that depends on values of the $\Gamma$ function.

Comment: Why $\Gamma$ function?

Comment: Check [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270721/how-to-evaluate-the-integral-int-ex3dx). The third answer has something similar as why you can use a $\Gamma$ function.