# How to solve this integral $\int _0^{\infty} e^{-x^3+2x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, airy-functions

My classmate asked me about this integral:$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^3+2x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
but I have no idea how to do it. What's the closed form of it? I guess it may be related to the Airy function.

Comment: According to [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_%28differential_algebra%29) on primitives, there is no expression in terms of simple functions.

Comment: Would the answer in [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270721/how-to-evaluate-the-integral-int-ex3dx) help? Tom-Tom is right, but maybe you can write it in terms of power series.

Comment: Is your classmate a friend ? Because such a gift would be making me crazy ! By the way, your guess about Airy function was very good. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I will kill him- -!

Comment: Try to find another one to challenge him ! There are plenty of them in this splendid site.

Comment: @Tom-Tom Special function？

Comment: I've tried to define $$\varphi(\lambda)=\int_0^\infty \exp\left[-x^3-3\lambda x^2-3\left(\lambda^2-\frac43\right)x-\lambda^3+\frac43
\lambda-\frac{37}{27}\right]\mathrm dx. $$You want $\varphi(-\frac23)$. Computing $\varphi'(\lambda)$ gives $\varphi'(\lambda)=\frac{37}{27}\varphi(\lambda)+\exp(-\lambda^3+\frac43\lambda-\frac{37}{27})$ but I can't see how to go beyond that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *I guess it may be related to the [Airy function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function).*

You guessed well. In general, we have $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\exp\Big(-x^2(x+3a)\Big)~dx~=~\frac2{e^{2a^3}}\cdot\frac{\text{Bi}\Big(3^{2/3}~a^2\Big)}{3^{4/3}}-$

$-a\cdot~_2F_2\bigg(\bigg[\dfrac12~,~1\bigg]~;~\bigg[\dfrac23~,~\dfrac43\bigg]~;~-4a^3\bigg).~$ In this particular case, $a=-\dfrac23.$

Comment: Very nice!Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a closed form that includes the generalized hypergeometric functions. They themselves can be expressed in a series, so you might be able to trace back the solution to some kind of series expression of the integrand:

[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate+Exp[-x^3%2B2+x^2+%2B1]+from+0+to+Infinity](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate+Exp[-x%5E3%2B2+x%5E2+%2B1]+from+0+to+Infinity)

My approach would be to take the solution and write the functions as a hypergeometric series.

Comment: oh god,hypergeometic series⋯⋯

Comment: I also don't know how helpful that approach will actually be...but for the record here are the relations: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AiryFunctions.html