# Determine (or evaluate) the sum of the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k+1)k!}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Determine (or evaluate) the sum of the series
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k+1)k!}, \ \ \ x\in\mathbb R^{+}$$
The best that I have managed to do is
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k+1)k!}<\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\left(x^{2}\right)^k}{(k+1)!}=\frac{1}{x^2}\left(e^{x^2}-x^2-1\right)$$
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$x\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k+1)k!}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int\dfrac{(x^2)^k}{k!}$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{(x^2)^k}{k!}=e^{x^2}-1$$

Comment: Excuse me, but maybe it is: $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k+1)k!}=\frac{1}{x}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int\dfrac{(x^2)^k}{k!}$.

Comment: @Mark, Thanks for your observation.

Comment: Thank you. But, $\int (e^{x^2}-1) dx$ isn't know.

Comment: @Mark, See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270721/how-to-evaluate-the-integral-int-ex3dx