# Integral of $e^{mx^{3}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function, indefinite-integrals

The question asks for the integral of $e^{mx^{3}}.$ How do I calculate the antiderivative of a function that has $e^{x^{3}}$ lets say. I want to make sure I know how to take the antiderivative of exponential functions.

Comment: Is it $e^m x^3$, $\left(e^{mx}\right)^3$ or $e^{mx^3}$? Exponentiation is not associative, hence e^x^3 is an ambiguous notation.

Comment: Its the third option you put

Comment: Straight from *Mathematica*:  $-\frac{x \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3},-m x^3\right)}{3 \sqrt[3]{-m x^3}}$

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Lol, you took the easy route to that answer.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies! I dont think my teacher meant to put this in the review. I haven't learned gamma yet idk what that is lol

Comment: Repeated question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270721/how-to-evaluate-the-integral-int-ex3dx

Comment: @Chris You can do it with the exponential integral if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $mt^3=-u,$

$$\int_0^xe^{mt^3}\ dt=-\int_0^{mx^3}\frac1{3\sqrt[3]{mu}}e^{-u}\ du=-\frac1{3\sqrt[3]{m}}\gamma\left(\frac23,mx^3\right)$$

where $\gamma(a,b)$ is the [lower incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).